# Massive URLs being recorded due to search redirects - are bots going into a loop and slowing down website

Tags: html, forms

I'm looking at a client's website and using Screaming Frog to give a general analysis and it is recording massively long URLs due to what I think are search redirects - see Example below.

I'm concerned that it could be using up resource bandwidth and leading to slowing the website down. I'm assuming there is an issue with the form being used - see below - but what is likely to be the cause? and is it an easy fix - unfortunately I don't have access to the code but at least I can pass on the info for the developer to sort.

### Example

```
https://example.co.uk/directory/example-product-number-one/??search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&search-redirect=true&make=car&model=all&min-price=all&max-price=all&body-style=all&transmission=all&colour=all&retailer-location=all
```

Note: This is actually a shortened version of the URL

### This is the form

```
<form id="uc-search" method="GET" action="https://example.co.uk/used-product-search/">
<input type="hidden" name="order-by" value="ID">
<input type="hidden" name="order" value="asc">

<select name="make" class="select-make">
    <option value="all">All makes</option>
    <option value="bish">Bish</option>
    <option value="bash">Bash</option>
    <option value="boogie">Boogie</option>
    <option value="other-stuff">Other Stuff</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="all">All models</option>
    <option value="bish-1">Bish-1</option>
    <option value="bish-2">Bish-2</option>
    <option value="bish-3">Bish-3</option>
    <option value="bish-4">Bish-4</option>
    <option value="bish-5">Bish-5</option>
    <option value="bish-6">Bish-6</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="all">All models</option>
    <option value="bash-1">Bash-1</option>
    <option value="bash-2">Bash-2</option>
    <option value="bash-3">Bash-3</option>
    <option value="bash-4">Bash-4</option>
    <option value="bash-5">Bash-5</option>
    <option value="bash-6">Bash-6</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="all">All models</option>
    <option value="boogie-1">Boogie-1</option>
    <option value="boogie-2">Boogie-2</option>
    <option value="boogie-3">Boogie-3</option>
    <option value="boogie-4">Boogie-4</option>
    <option value="boogie-5">Boogie-5</option>
    <option value="boogie-6">Boogie-6</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="all">All models</option>
    <option value="other-stuff-1">other-stuff-1</option>
    <option value="other-stuff-2">other-stuff-2</option>
    <option value="other-stuff-3">other-stuff-3</option>
    <option value="other-stuff-4">other-stuff-4</option>
    <option value="other-stuff-5">other-stuff-5</option>
    <option value="other-stuff-6">other-stuff-6</option>
</select>

<select name="model" disabled>
    <option value="all">All models</option>
</select>

<select name="min-price">
    <option value="all">Min price</option>
    <option value="10000">&pound;10,000</option>
    <option value="20000">&pound;20,000</option>
    <option value="30000">&pound;30,000</option>
    <option value="40000">&pound;40,000</option>
    <option value="50000">&pound;50,000</option>
    <option value="60000">&pound;60,000</option>
    <option value="70000">&pound;70,000</option>
    <option value="80000">&pound;80,000</option>
    <option value="90000">&pound;90,000</option>
    <option value="100000">&pound;100,000</option>
    <option value="110000">&pound;110,000</option>
    <option value="120000">&pound;120,000</option>
</select>

<select name="max-price">
    <option value="all">Max price</option>
    <option value="10000">&pound;10,000</option>
    <option value="20000">&pound;20,000</option>
    <option value="30000">&pound;30,000</option>
    <option value="40000">&pound;40,000</option>
    <option value="50000">&pound;50,000</option>
    <option value="60000">&pound;60,000</option>
    <option value="70000">&pound;70,000</option>
    <option value="80000">&pound;80,000</option>
    <option value="90000">&pound;90,000</option>
    <option value="100000">&pound;100,000</option>
    <option value="110000">&pound;110,000</option>
    <option value="120000">&pound;120,000</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

TIA, 
Kevin

Comment: If it is indeed a problem with redirects from that form, you need to verify that.   Can you put `https://example.co.uk/used-product-search/?order-by=ID&order=asc&make=bish&min-price=10000&max-price=120000` (or some similar real url) through a redirect checker (or `curl --head`) on the command line and add the results of that to your question?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request-URI Too Large</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at default-94_136_34_249 Port 443</address>
</body></html>

Comment: I'm wondering if this can be simply fixed by changing the GET to POST

Comment: How did you obtain that?  Not with `curl --head` which only shows headers.   Which redirect checker did you use?

Comment: Another way to investigate would be to use the developer tools built into Firefox or Chrome.   Going to the network tab and submitting the form will till you all the requests being made to the server.    There is likely some redirect chain involved here and you need to see all those steps to be able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Or post the real URL so that we can check it out for you